# Accept all characters if string present but only up to occurence of character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression that matches strings that contain a certain string but only up to the first occurrence of a character.

In this case, I want it to match a string that contains **foo.com** but ignores everything up to and including the first occurrence of a question mark.

e.g. **https://www.foo.com/some/folder/page.cgi**?ignore=params

I know that I can get all the characters before `?` with the following regex:

```
(^.*)(?=\?)
```

And that I can limit the strings found to those containing **foo.com** with the following:

```
^.*(foo.com){1}.*$
```

But can I do this in one expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[^?]*foo\.com[^?]*
```

**Explanation:**

```
^          # Start of string
[^?]*      # Any number of characters except ?
foo\.com   # foo.com
[^?]*      # Any number of characters except ?
```